# Why is the letter 'X' given importance in mathematics?

Tags: history, mathematics, consonants

In mathematics the letter 'X' is always given importance over other letters. Why is it so?

Comment: Off topic: Not a question about **English**, since *x* was used for this in other European languages before English began to predominate in mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Florian Cajori, in [*A History of Mathematical Notations*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_byqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA381), writes (page 381):

> The use of *z*, *y*, *x* .... to represent unknowns is due to René Descartes, in his *La géométrie* (1637). Without comment, he introduces the use of the first letters of the alphabet to signify *known* quantities and the use of the last letters to signify *unknown* quantities. His own language is: "... l'autre, LN, est ½*a* la moitié de l'autre quantité connue, qui estoit multipliée par *z*, que ie suppose estre la ligne inconnue."
>
> [...] As co-ordinates, he uses later only *x* and *y*. In equations, in the third book of the *Géométrie*, *x* predominates. In manuscripts written in the interval 1629–40, the unknown *z* occurs only once.
>
> [...] Some historical writers have focused their attention upon the *x*, disregarding the *y* and *z*, and the other changes in notation made by Descartes; these writers have endeavored to connect this *x* with older symbols or with Arabic words. [...] But Descartes' mode of introducing the knowns *a*, *b*, *c*, etc., and the unknowns *z*, *y*, *x* makes this hypothesis improbable.

As for the reason why *x* is more common than *y* and *z*:

> [Tropfke argues] that the resemblence of *x* and [a symbol for the unknown used by early German writers] may account for the fact that in the latter part of Descartes' *Géométrie* the *x* occurs more frequently than *z* and *y*. Eneström, on the other hand, inclines to the view that the predominance of *x* over *y* and *z* is due to typographical reasons, type for *x* being more plentiful because of the more frequent occurrence of the letter *x*, to *y* and *z*, in the French and Latin languages.

Answer (score 6):

Representing unknowns as *x, y, z* was proposed by [René Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes). He also proposed to represent knowns as *a, b, c*. Others picked it up, and basically that is all there is to it. Descartes lived in the 17th century, so the convention isn't that old, either. And as you can see, *x* is but one in a sequence of letters having "importance", it just happens to be the first in that sequence and is thus used more often than *z*. Pure chance.

Quoting the "Mathematical legacy" section of that Wikipedia article:

> One of Descartes' most enduring legacies was his development of Cartesian or analytic geometry, which uses algebra to describe geometry. He "invented the convention of representing unknowns in equations by *x, y*, and *z*, and knowns by *a, b*, and *c*". He also "pioneered the standard notation" that uses superscripts to show the powers or exponents; for example, the *4* used in *x<sup>4</sup>* to indicate squaring of squaring. He was first to assign a fundamental place for algebra in our system of knowledge, and believed that algebra was a method to automate or mechanize reasoning, particularly about abstract, unknown quantities. European mathematicians had previously viewed geometry as a more fundamental form of mathematics, serving as the foundation of algebra.

Comment: I'd add that the primary advantage of *x* as a starting point over *a* is that being at the far end of the alphabet, and being relatively rare in use (not only in the Latin and French that Descartes wrote in, but also in most other European languages, including English), it would be less likely to be confused with some other use. He also sometimes favoured P, Q, R... in cases where he had used O as an abbreviation of *origin*.

Comment: Oh and of course there's also *i, j, k* for index variables, and *n, m* for parameters. I am not sure who first came up with these, though. It stands to reason they are more recent.